# How to make MQTT broker docker image accessible to devices in LAN?

Tags: docker, mqtt, lan

I have a a docker container with a few images running there. I run them via docker-compose up command. On my device everything works well with localhost but I want to make so that other devices in the same network will be able to access the MQTT broker as well. How do I do that?

Currently, in my code I do this:

```
ws:localhost:9001
```

But since this localhost applies only for the device that runs docker, another laptop won't be able to use it. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You use the LAN IP address of your machine (the one hosting the docker containers) in place of `localhost`.

We have no way of knowing what that address may be, but it could start with `192.168.x.x` or may be `10.x.x.x`

Comment: what if I have to use it in multiple network and it has to get the ip address of the device that runs it?

Comment: Yes, if you are deploying the containers on multiple machines on different networks then you need to know the IP address of those machines. You can look at using something like mDNS to assign a hostname to that machine that can be used to find the machine on the LAN

Comment: An example of automatically setting up mDNS names for docker containers https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/09/22/nginx-proxy-avahi-helper/

Answer (score 0):

By default, Docker has a "bridge" network that will bridge your container to the outside world.  Just use the IP address of the computer where your MQTT Broker Container is running, and port 9001, and it should work fine.

If you need to run it on an internal Docker network, you will have to use something like an ADC or TCP Proxy of some sort to allow access to it.